# Overlay scrollbar on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I've got a problem, I have an div, that changes height, but when it has overflow, the scrollbar change it's width, are the any way to make this scrollbar "overlay" the div without changing the width.

On Chrome there is there is:

```
overflow: overlay;
```

Although on firefox it does not work. Are there any solution? Doesn't matter if it is javascript, jquery or css.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not able to replicate this myself. Do you have the code that is exhibiting this behavior?

Comment: I can't show the code, it is pretty big, but I have this one: https://jsfiddle.net/odg84npf/3/

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use "overlay" since is it not standard. Instead try a plugin like [perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar/) which reveals the scrollbar on hover.

Comment: Are there any other solution? It isn't possible to add this plugin to the project

Comment: Well, you could set a max height and overflow on the element (e.g. `.wrapper p { max-height:200px; overflow: auto; }` - see https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/odg84npf/4/

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/perfect-scrollbar

Comment: Answer should be updated since your plugin link is 404.